# Equivalence of Gaussian measures on Hilbert space

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, gaussian

Suppose we have 2 nondegenerate Gaussian measures given by  N(0,T) and N(0,S) supported on a separable Hilbert space H. T and S are such that eigenbasis of S lies in the cameron martin space of N(0,T). Furthermore, let S and T have the same eigenvalues.
Does there exist a permutation of set of eigenpairs of S such that the resulting Gaussian measure(after the permutation) is absolutely continuous wrt N(0,T)?

Comment: I am not sure I really understand the question (what do you mean by "permutation of set of eigenpairs"?), but the kind of example you might want to keep in mind is where $H = R^2$ and the two matrices $S$ and $T$ are of rank $1$, but with different eigenvectors.

Comment: By "permutation" do you mean an operator that permutes the eigenvectors of S?

Comment: Both Gaussians are non degenerate(just made the edit). @nate yes, I mean an operator R which permutes eigenvectors of S and the resulting Gaussian is N(0,SR).

Comment: I meant N(0,R'SR).